# Navigation bar suddenly on top instead of bottom HTML

Tags: html, css, navigation

My navbar was fine and fixed at the bottom, until I added a link to the google font API and an additional font option in the html. I commented out everything I changed, then I deleted it, but nothing has worked. The navigation should be exactly as it is, just at the bottom. 
Here is my html:

```
<div class="navbar">
<nav>
    <a href="otherpage.html">Blog</a>
    <a href="otherpage.html">Linguistics Facts</a>
    <a href="otherpage.html">More About Me</a>
</nav>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar a {
    float: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    margin: 15px; /*experimental*/
    background-color: #f7b733;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'PassionTea', 'Amatic SC';
    font-size: 170%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing ? Can you post a picture of issue.?

Comment: nav should be at the bottom of what? `float: center` is invalid btw

Comment: Yeah, I got ahead of myself and tried to use a property I didn't fully understand. It should've been at the bottom of the page, but I got rid of the float property and changed the position to absolute, and this resolved the issue. Honestly I'm not sure how I got it right before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height: desired height;
}
```

To stick your menu to the bottom of your viewport you need to set position fixed not relative.You don't need list-style:none; because you don't have any list on the nav tag.